# NSDictionary of NSDictionaries

Tags: objective-c, ios, arrays, xcode, nsdictionary

I'm having trouble with the following code to create an NSDictionary of NSDictionaries.  There is no compile error, but during runtime, it fails on this code.

```
NSDictionary *section0 = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                            [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                                @"Caller ID", @"label",
                                @"name", @"field",
                                @"Call", @"fieldType", nil
                            ], 0,
                            [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                                @"Number", @"label",
                                @"number", @"field",
                                @"Call", @"fieldType", nil
                            ], 1,
                            nil
                         ];
```

This is my first app, so any help you can provide is greatly appreciated.

Comment: What does it fail with?  what error?

Comment: My 2 cents - I don't like big blocks of code like this.  It makes it really hard to debug - the whole line succeeds or fails.  It might mean more lines but would have created it separately so you can add logging etc... in between.  Innocent mistakes become much harder to spot.

Comment: Is there a reason your are doing an NSDictionary of NSDictionaries? You are assigning an int as a key when it need to be a string. It looks like you want an array of dictionaries. If you use @craig's example below this will fix your error, but I think you are wanting an array of dictionaries.

Comment: I agree with @syclonefx - if all the values in your top-level dictionary will be keyed by a number that starts at 0 and increments by 1, then you should be using an NSMutableArray, and simply adding/removing the dictionaries from this array. (And you can get them using the 'key' which is just the index: **[myArray objectAtIndex:0]**)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Your keys also have to be objects. (In addition to the values.) You're using `0` and `1` int types as keys. You should instead use the following:

```
[NSNumber numberWithInt:0];
```

Thus, your dictionary code would look like:

```
NSDictionary *section0 = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                            [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                                @"Caller ID", @"label",
                                @"name", @"field",
                                @"Call", @"fieldType", nil
                            ], [NSNumber numberWithInt:0],
                            [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                                @"Number", @"label",
                                @"number", @"field",
                                @"Call", @"fieldType", nil
                            ], [NSNumber numberWithInt:1],
                            nil
                         ];
```

Answer (score 0):

Use literals:

```
NSNumber *number = @0 ; // equal [NSNumber numberWithInt:0]
```

In your code:

```
NSDictionary *section0 = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                         [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                             @"Caller ID", @"label",
                             @"name", @"field",
                             @"Call", @"fieldType", nil
                         ], @0,
                         [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                             @"Number", @"label",
                             @"number", @"field",
                             @"Call", @"fieldType", nil
                         ], @1,
                         nil
                     ];
```